# Alexa Skill - Retrieve User's mail within multi-turn dialog

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am developping an Alexa Skill within the one the user has to provide a serie of answers to my backend (node.js) in order to get the right result. I would like to send this result by email.

Is it possible to retrieve the user's email through the API put at disposal by AWS using the Dialog.delegate method?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There is **no** built in method can get you the current user email id or any personal info.

But with authentication you can. See this [blog post](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/Tx3CX1ETRZZ2NPC/alexa-account-linking-5-steps-to-seamlessly-link-your-alexa-skill-with-login-with-amazon). You'll need to create an Amazon App and link it to your amazon skill using Account Linking. For the first time when you ask for the email, user has to accept access with their Alexa app. You can then save this email in your DB for future purposes. This is a long but recommended method.

The simplest method: Whenever the game is finished you can manually ask the user for email address. But Alexa may not recognize email address spoken by users properly and might break your app. I don't know, but maybe Alexa will reject your app for asking personal info this way!